# fish: escaping `^` in sed

Tags: escaping, fish

In Fish shell, try to escape `^` in `[^anything]` in `sed`, however, it does not work.

I tried using single quotes (`'s///'`), double quotes (`"s///"`, escapig via single or double slash (`/`), nothing works.

I’d like a solution for both single **and** double quotes in `sed` command.

```
$ echo 'cd $OLDPWD $argv' | sed $sed_options "s/cd \([\^ ]\) \$argv/cd \1/g" -

$ echo 'cd $OLDPWD $argv' | sed $sed_options 's/cd \([\^ ]\) \$argv/cd \1/g' -
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In Fish shell, try to escape ^ in [^anything] in sed, however, it does not work.

So, the thing is you don't need to escape the `^` for fish's benefit[0].

If you want an inverted character set, you should just use it without a backslash.

E.g.

```
echo abc | sed -e 's/[^a]/+/g'
```

will replace both the "b" and the "c" with a "+", because neither is an "a".

> I’d like a solution for both single and double quotes in sed command.

This is the same in single- and double-quotes.

```
echo 'cd $OLDPWD $argv' | sed $sed_options "s/cd \([^ ]\) \$argv/cd \1/g"
```

---

[0] Technically versions before fish 3 used it to denote stderr redirections, but only at the start of a token, and only outside of quotes. None of which is applicable here.

Comment: Well, I tried that and it does not work. I have no ideawhy. Btw, I installed Fish v3.0.2 in Termux. `echo 'cd $OLDPWD $argv' | sed "s/cd \([^ ]\) \$argv/cd \1/g" -` outputs `cd $OLDPWD $argv`. Same with single quotes.

Comment: The `sed` is wrong in other ways - `\([^ ]\)` is _one character_. That means it'd have to look like `cd x $argv` to match. Use `\([^ ]*\)` "a number of characters that aren't a space.